# How to run Node.js on Google Colab for Brain.js?

Tags: node.js, google-colaboratory, brain.js

LSTM networks in Brain.js take a long time to train even with a very small dataset. I decided to use Google Colab to see if things would speed up:

By putting this in the Google Colab cells, I was able to run it with Node.js:

`%%script node`

I thought the LSTM network would train very quickly, but it continued to train slowly, even slower than on my computer. Does Google Colab impose any resource restrictions on cells with `%%script node`? Is there a way to remove that supposed restriction?

I didn't anything more after this.